# Unable to generate django javascript i18n catalog

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

I am trying to generate the JS catalog for translating my JS strings.

Folowing the docs, I am trying

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l de
processing locale de
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
msguniq: error while opening "[project_root]/locale/djangojs.pot" for reading: No such file or directory
$ man msguniq
$ django-admin.py makemessages -d django -l de
processing locale de
$
```

Which fails, but makemessages works for django domain.

Comment: What version of ``gettext``, Django and Python are you using?

Comment: `GNU gettext-runtime 0.18.1`, django=1.6.0, python 2.7, ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could not reproduce using same versions of gettext, django, python (2.7.3) and ubuntu. I suggest checking [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) once again. Could you post more details about your ``urls.py`` and translated JavaScript files?

Comment: I stumbled over the same error message, and recognized after half an hour that I did not have any messages to translate in my app. Adding a translatable string into my app, fixed it :D

Comment: @ThomasKremmel: Thanks, you write this as answer, I'll accept it. I was hitting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that there was no string to be translated (the error message could be better!). Adding a translatable string (e.g. `{% trans 'dummy' %}`) fixed it.

Another problem could be outdated gettext version, try upgrading it:

```
apt-get install gettext
```

Comment: Not sure how this became the accepted answer. See @ThomasKremmel comment reply. This is a confused accepted answer. The real problem was not that gettext was not installed, but that there was no string to be translated (the error message could be better!). Adding a translatable string (e.g. {% trans 'dummy' %}) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the previous notes from documentation and other answers, you need to put the JavaScript code in a file inside the static folder (also you need to collect the static files) in order to the `djangojs.po` to be generated. Because Django by default look at this destination when dealing with JS files.