# djangojs makemessage fails - djangojs.pot: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, gettext

I'm trying to run this command `django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en` with no avail. I already tried what is told here: [Unable to generate django javascript i18n catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802624/unable-to-generate-django-javascript-i18n-catalog)

I'm currently running gettext version 0.18.3

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog
from django.contrib import admin

js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('MyApp',),
}

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'MyApp.views.test'),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict),
)
```

Relevant settings

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/Users/Saturnix/PycharmProjects/TranslationTest/MyApp/locale',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/Saturnix/PycharmProjects/TranslationTest/templates/',
)
```

(I've also tried to put the template folder inside of MyApp and adjust the settings accordingly: same result).

views.py

```
def test(request):
    return render_to_response("test.html", locals())
```

test.html (in templates folder)

```
... some html ...
{% trans 'HELLO_STRING_TEMPLATE' %}
... some javascript ...
document.write(gettext('HELLO_STRING_JS'));
```

As I run `django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en` I get

> CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
>
> msguniq: error during the reading of "/Users/Saturnix/PycharmProjects/TranslationTest/MyApp/locale/djangojs.pot": No such file or directory

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

This obscure error message basically means that `makemessages` found nothing to translate.